# Trying to remove attribute from HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, html

Ive made a quiz app, with HTML and JS only and im trying to remove an id from a element which has the attribute, however when i run the code to remove it my JS doesnt find the attribute in any of the elements, if i manually inspect i can see it in the html?

i do add this element in the JS above it, could this be because the DOM hasnt updated?

```
choices.forEach(choice => {
choice.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(!acceptingAnswers) return;

    acceptingAnswers = false;
    const selectedChoice = e.target;
    const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];

    const classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';


    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

    if (classToApply === 'correct'){
        incrementScore(CORRECT_BONUS);
    } else{
        for(let i = 0; i<currentChoices.length; i++){
            if(currentChoices[i].dataset["number"] != currentQuestion.answer) continue;

            currentChoices[i].parentElement.classList.add("correct");
            currentChoices[i].id = "correctAnswer";
            
        }
    }
    
    correctAnswer = document.getElementById("correctAnswer");
    

    setTimeout(() =>{
        selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
        if(correctAnswer){
            correctAnswer.parentElement.classList.remove("correct");
            for (choice of document.querySelectorAll(".choice-text")) {
                if (choice.hasAttribute("correctAnswer")){
                    choice.getAttribute("correctAnswer");
                    choice.removeAttribute("correctAnswer");
                    console.log("Removed")
                }
            }
            
        }
        getNewQuestion();
        
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: What is the error u getting

Comment: Back to the drawing board. There's absolutely no need to move IDs around. Also,  `correctAnswer` is not a valid HTML attribute. Use `data-*` attribute instead.

Comment: No error is displaying, but the code does not run in the if statement, so it is not finding the attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed some things around and used a class instead of id which seems to work much better.

```
choices.forEach(choice => {
choice.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(!acceptingAnswers) return;

    acceptingAnswers = false;
    const selectedChoice = e.target;
    const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];

    const classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';


    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

    if (classToApply === 'correct'){
        incrementScore(CORRECT_BONUS);
    } else{
        for(let i = 0; i<currentChoices.length; i++){
            if(currentChoices[i].dataset["number"] != currentQuestion.answer) continue;

            currentChoices[i].parentElement.classList.add("correct");
            currentChoices[i].classList.add("correctAnswer");
            
        }
    }
    
    correctAnswer = document.querySelector(".correctAnswer");
    

    setTimeout(() =>{
        selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
        if(correctAnswer){
            correctAnswer.parentElement.classList.remove("correct");
            for (choice of document.querySelectorAll(".choice-text")) {
                if (choice.classList.contains("correctAnswer")){
                    choice.classList.remove("correctAnswer");
                }
            }
        }
        getNewQuestion();
        
    }, 1000);
```